# Is there a way to assign id to every item on a gridview?

Tags: android

Is there a way to assign id to every item on a gridview? I'm working with a gridview and I populate it like this:

```
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflator=LayoutInflater.from(this.mContext);
        View layout=inflator.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, parent, false);
        ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView == null) {
            // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(170, 170));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setPadding(4, 4, 4, 4);
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }


        return imageView;
    }

    // references to our images
    private Integer[] mThumbIds = {

            R.drawable.container_circle_blue,
            R.drawable.container_circle_dblue,
            R.drawable.container_circle_green,
            R.drawable.container_circle_yellow,
            R.drawable.container_circle_red,

            R.drawable.container_square_blue,
            R.drawable.container_square_dblue,
            R.drawable.container_square_green,
            R.drawable.container_square_yellow,
            R.drawable.container_square_red,



            R.drawable.container_hexagone_blue,
            R.drawable.container_hexagone_dblue,
            R.drawable.container_hexagone_green,
            R.drawable.container_hexagone_yellow,
            R.drawable.container_hexagone_red,

            R.drawable.container_star_blue,
            R.drawable.container_star_dblue,
            R.drawable.container_star_green,
            R.drawable.container_star_yellow,
            R.drawable.container_star_red,

            R.drawable.container_triangle_blue,
            R.drawable.container_triangle_dblue,
            R.drawable.container_triangle_green,
            R.drawable.container_triangle_yellow,
            R.drawable.container_triangle_red,
    };
```

and I need to add every item an Id so I can later work with collisions and make comparisons with every imageview there and others

Comment: Are you still looking for answer? or you forget to accept the upvoted answer?

Comment: sorry I forgot to mark it as the correct answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set `Tag` instead of assigning an id to the dynamic created view.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflator=LayoutInflater.from(this.mContext);
    View layout=inflator.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, parent, false);
    ImageView imageView;
    if (convertView == null) {
        // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
        imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(170, 170));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setPadding(4, 4, 4, 4);
    } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }
    // set tag
    imageView.setTag(position);

    return imageView;
}
```

Later when getting view in `onClick` or `onItemClicked`, you can do something like this-

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    Object tag = view.getTag();
    if (tag instanceOf Integer) {
        int pos = (Integer)tag;
        // use position to identify that item.
    }
}
```

As you are new to this, I would suggest to use `RecyclerView` if using `Listview`. If still you need to use normal adapter then go with `ViewHolder` pattern.

Answer (score 0):

The position effectively acts as an id. Or I have missed the point?

Comment: I was thinking something like this: id= "circle_blue_container" and the other image would have the same id and if they are equal, then the imageresource would change, i'm thinking of doing it this way because everytime the app opens, the order of the elements in the gridview change